# TypeORM/NestJS: how to handle auto-reconnection if database fails/crashs?

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I would like to know if there is a parameter or a custom way to try auto-reconnection to the database using Typeorm/NestJS (Postgresql) if the connection is lost.

Currently, when I stop my database, NestJS blocks every coming requests and even if I restart my database NestJS will not try to reconnect to it. I have to restart my NestJS app....

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Finally I just did this:

```js
// seems to be mandatory otherwise poolErrorHandler doesn't get called if database dies
process.on('unhandledRejection', () => {});

const databaseConfigModule = TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: (config: ConfigService<Environment>) => ({
        type: 'postgres',
        host: config.get<DatabaseConfig>('database').host,
        port: config.get<DatabaseConfig>('database').port,
        username: config.get<DatabaseConfig>('database').user,
        password: config.get<DatabaseConfig>('database').password,
        database: config.get<DatabaseConfig>('database').database,
        entities: [],
        synchronize: true,
        autoLoadEntities: true,
        poolErrorHandler: async (err) => {
          const reconnection = setInterval(async () => {
            console.log('Retrying connection...');
            const connection = new DataSource({
              type: 'postgres',
              host: config.get<DatabaseConfig>('database').host,
              port: config.get<DatabaseConfig>('database').port,
              username: config.get<DatabaseConfig>('database').user,
              password: config.get<DatabaseConfig>('database').password,
              database: config.get<DatabaseConfig>('database').database,
            });
            const db = await connection.initialize();
            if (db.isInitialized) clearInterval(reconnection);
          }, 1000);
        },
      }),
    });
```